# Do Iphones or Android based phones have any support for ECN?

Tags: iphone, android, tcp

Do Iphones or Android based phones have any support for ECN? (ECN is Explicit Congestion Notification, a TCP extension) From the searching I have done, the current answer appears to be "no".  Though given that Android phones are based upon the Linux kernel it looks like Android phones, at least in theory, could have ECN turned on rather easily.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance. What is ECN?

Comment: @GSree: Explicit Congestion Notification, a TCP extension.

Answer (score 1):

In June 2015, Apple Inc. announced that ECN is now enabled in OSX 10.11 and iOS 9. Note that most ISPs don't currently enable ECN in their routers, so ECN is unlikely to be used by your apple devices immediately. Apple hopes that enabling ECN in devices will incentivize ISPs to enable it in routers as well. The announcement itself is shown in this [video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=719), and the [wikipedia page on ECN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicit_Congestion_Notification) also has some information.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I see this is a very old post, but as it's currently on top of Google-
On a Verizon Galaxy S5 4.4.2 dialing *#*#87326#*#* will toast a message stating that ECN is either enabled or disabled.